# Как с помощью Selenium получить доступ к элементу, если в коде страницы присутствуют "shadow-root"?

Tags: python, dom, selenium, selenium-webdriver, автоматизация

[image: код страницы]

Сразу скажу, что я не программист и в терминах не силен. Извиняйте.
До недавнего времени все было ОК и Selenium.webdriver мог найти любой элемент при помощи 'find_element_by_xpath'. Но однажды в коде страницы появились строки "#shadow-root" и моя автоматизация сломалась, теперь Selenium не может найти ничего из того, что  находится глубже "#shadow-root". Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно с помощью Selenium получить доступ, например, к указанной на картинке кнопке?

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver в чистом виде, грубо говоря, не поддерживает работу с shadow домами, ищи какой-нибудь фреймворк для js. 
Если разрабатываешь с помощью Пайтона, то посмотри какие нибудь пакеты для этого (pip) 
[Тут можно почитать подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36140807/7723489)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно тебе поможет этот туториал - https://learn.javascript.ru/shadow-dom
и сказанное там о селекторе!

В том же вопросе, что предложил Naumov Ivan, но другой ответ, как раз говорит о том, что ShadowDom можно найти по селектору - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36165583/7685008