# как достать из #shadow-root (open) текст при помощи Selenium на python

Tags: python, selenium, parse

```py
import data

import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

try:
    s = Service(executable_path=r"C:\Users\dimoc\PycharmProjects\steam_bot\Chromedriver_win\chromedriver.exe")
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(
        r"--load-extension=C:\Users\dimoc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\jjicbefpemnphinccgikpdaagjebbnhg\3.0.3_0")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url=data.skin_link)

    all_skins_and_price = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'market_listing_row')
    skins_list = all_skins_and_price[1:]

    for i in range(0, 1):
        skin_price = skins_list[i].find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'market_listing_price_with_fee').text
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)

        skin_float = skins_list[i].find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'csgofloat-item-row-wrapper')

        shadow_root = skin_float.shadow_root
        shadow_content = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div')
        shadow_content.text


except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Я пытаюсь достать значение `float` с сайта steam с расширением `csgoFloat market checker`, но `shadow_content` не выдает текст.

Comment: подобный вопрос есть тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/902416/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-selenium-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82

Comment: Там используется старая версия Selenium

Comment: Есть предложение как это исправить, как с тобой можно связаться?